# not getting a route in jobeer symfony2 tutorial

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony trying to do the jobeet tutorial, currently working on day 3. I managed to register the `docrtrine-fixtures-bundle` and created the CRUD for the job.  However, if i go to `..../jobeet/job` it tells me:

> No route found for "GET /job"

If i type in browser: `jobeet/app_dev.php` or `jobeet` it works fine for both environments. As soon as i type `jobeet/app_dev.php/job` or `jobeet/job` i get the error.

### AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml:

```
app_job:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/job.yml"
    prefix:   /job
```

### AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/job.yml:

```
job_index:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Job:index" }
    methods:  GET

job_show:
    path:     /{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Job:show" }
    methods:  GET

job_new:
    path:     /new
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Job:new" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

job_edit:
    path:     /{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Job:edit" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

job_delete:
    path:     /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Job:delete" }
    methods:  DELETE
```

Can anyone help me what is missing or doing wrong?

Tnx

Walter

Comment: But you don't have route for `/job` do you??

Comment: I tought it was in routing file ?

Comment: But if not how would i be adding the proper routing for the ../job ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to dump your routing?
use this command in your terminal

```
php app/console debug:router | grep job
```

You should get `jobeet/app_dev.php/job/` instead of `jobeet/app_dev.php/job`

Comment: I solved the problem, in the app/config routing file it was telling symfony it was using annotations as routing. I made it point only to the routing file in the resources map and deleted the first default controller that came with symfony when i installed it. so now symfony knows to look not for annotation routing but in the routing file wich was pointing to resources/confige,routing job.yml. hope this will help other newbies if they run in the same problem

Answer (score 0):

so make sure you set up your symfony right. Point to the routing file in the resources map. And dont tell symfony to use annotation if you aint using it :)

tnx for the responces